# HTC People Widget - Improve Touch Accuracy?

Tags: app-widgets, htc-sense, htc-evo

I have HTC's people widget on one of my home screens.  I like its functionality but sometimes when I touch a contact, another one gets selected. A completely different contact gets the green selection box and it starts to call them.  With my luck this usually results in calling my parents at some ungodly hour.

I've used touch visualizers to see if that area of my touch screen is having problems but all looks fine. The people widget is the only thing that seems to be affected.

I've also tried removing and re-adding the widget.  Is there a fix for this? Or a comparable replacement?

Answer (score 1):

You could try [Call Confirm](http://www.appbrain.com/app/net.nanabit.callconfirm), which gives a popup to confirm if you want to call said person.

I haven't tried it myself, but I've heard it is recommended for accidental touch screen issues.

QR Code for Call Confirm:

[image]

Comment: It's not that I accidentally touch the widget and call someone.  It's that I touch the widget to call person A but the software has a bug in that is selects person B to call.

Answer (score 1):

I believe I observed a similar issue... I simply waited a few seconds and then pushed the screen side-to-side without leaving the screen. I saw the widget sort of refresh with the contacts back in order.

Answer (score 0):

There probably isn't much you can do to fix HTC's widget. On the other hand you can purchase LauncherPro Plus which has its own *People Widget* which works perfectly fine for me.

LauncherPro QR Code:

[image: LauncherPro QR Code]

Otherwise you can look around on the Market and I'm sure you'll find another *People Widget* somewhere.